# Set webpack to --host 0.0.0.0 not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I need to set the --host 0.0.0.0 for webpack. I am using Docker for local Wordpress development.
In my webpack.config.js file I currently have this under module.exports:

```
module.exports = merge.smartStrategy({
 'module.loaders': 'replace',
})(webpackConfig, desire(`${__dirname}/webpack.config.preset`));
```

How do I add the below to the module.exports above?

```
module.exports = {
//...
   devServer: {
     host: '0.0.0.0',
     disableHostCheck: true,
     watchOptions: {
       poll: true // Or you can set a value in milliseconds.
}
}
};
```

Also what do I need to do in my package.json file to ensure that webpack is using 0.0.0.0 as --host?

I have the following line in my package.json:

```
"start": "webpack --hide-modules --watch --config resources/assets/build/webpack.config.js",
```

Comment: Webpack probably needs elevated permissions in order to bind to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I am using Docker for local WordPress development so Docker is the new localhost how, and in order for Webpack to work I need to set it to host 0.0.0.0

Comment: Webpack itself doesn't serve anything on any host. The dev server does, but it doesn't look like your `start` script uses the dev server.

Comment: Right, what would I need to add here to use the dev server and host 0.0.0.0.          
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --config resources/assets/build/webpack.config.js",
    "build:production": "webpack --env.production --progress --config resources/assets/build/webpack.config.js",
    "build:profile": "webpack --progress --profile --json --config resources/assets/build/webpack.config.js",
    "start": "webpack --hide-modules --watch --config resources/assets/build/webpack.config.js",